old acrylic paint smell
We ended up painting a sheet a plywood thats mounted in our house with some old acrylic paint that when we opened smelt pretty bad, almost like sour smelling. We initially didn't think much of it, but after we painted it and did a little bit of research we realized that the paint had actually gone bad. Now it stills smells horrible. Should we be concerned about the toxic fumes (bacteria/mold)? Do I have to replace the sheet of plywood? Is there a way to get rid of the smell?

Scrape the paint off and repaint. Paint over the top, sealing the smell in. Remove the plywood (should be easy, it's mounted with some old acrylic paint) and replace it with new wood & paint. Lots of options...
